# Local Storage Issue- Angular 2

Tags: angular, authentication, local-storage

I have a local storage variable to store the data of the current authenticated games. This is the structure of my app.

**Open Games**

I have a table called OpenGames which has a list of games stored in the table. Now when I click on any of the games (lord of the rings) in the table, it authenticates and the name of the game authenticated is stored in the local Storage variable and routes to a page (for example: Display Game Page)  which displays the current stored name in the local storage.

In the first instance I realize the authenticated game is displayed on the Display Game Page but what happens is, when I go back to the OpenGames table to authenticate another game (Spiderman), the local storage still keeps the first game of which I authenticated. I will have to re-authenticate the Spiderman before the local storage will store Spiderman.

Checking logged console, when I authenticate the game, the local storage on the Display Game Page displays the older stored value before the details of new authenticated game is displayed.

My problem now is: How can I make sure that the authentication happens before the local storage saves the authenticated game?

**Auth**

```
constructor(private httpService: Http) {
    let currentGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'));    
}

authGame(game: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/example.com',({game: game }))
           .map((response: Response) => {

        let game_name:string = response && response.json().game.name;

        if (game_name ) {
            // store name in variable 
            this.game_name = game_name;

            localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify({game_name:game_name })

            console('Current Game is ' +game_name)
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });      

}
```

**Display Game Page**

```
constructor( private auth:AuthGame){
     this.currentGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'));    
     this.currentGame.game_name);
     console('Current Game is ' currentGame.game_name)
}
```

**updated Auth**

```
constructor(private httpService: Http) {

    let currentGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'));
}

authGame(game: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/example.com',({game: game }))
            .map((response: Response) => {         
        let game_name:string = response && response.json().game.name;

        if (game_name ) {
            // store name in variable 
            this.game_name = game_name;
            if(localStorage.getItem('currentGame')) {
                localstorage.removeItem('currentGame');
                localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify({game_name:game_name }))   
                console('Current Game is ' +game_name)
            }
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: before setting the local storage check whether it is already set if it already set then remove the local storage and set the new value to local storage

Comment: @ArunKumaresh i can really relate with your statement. if you could be more explanatory. But if i get you right, you mean, when i remove the local storage when i route from display game page  back to the open games table to authenticate another game, the application will throw an error saying `currentGame is null` since the display game page opens up before the authentication

Comment: can you add the code of what you have tried

Comment: @ArunKumaresh this is current code i have tried now.

Comment: How does the displayGame component look like? Especially the function that calls `authGame` and then routes?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'))
{
localStorage.removeItem('currentGame');
      localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify({game_name:game_name }))                    

}
```

Comment: in which component? My display page? with an ngDestroy?

Comment: no in the component where you're setting the local storage

Comment: You mean in my Auth component?

Comment: you're just checking whether it is already set or not if it already set remove the old value and set the new Value

Comment: Alright. But after trying that, i still get the same results as explained in the question

Comment: small typo i have used small s for local storage see my updated answer is auth component is called everytime when game is authenticated

Comment: Same issue persisting. I have been thinking that the display page component triggers first before the authentication component. Question update with  `console('Current Game is ' +game_name)` and `console('Current Game is ' currentGame.game_name)` in each component.  In the console, i see that the  ('Current Game is ' currentGame.game_name)` displays first with the old result and after in the console ('Current Game is ' +game_name)` is displayed which has the new authenticated game